# How to call a method from one component to another in angular

Tags: angular

I want to call a method in another component when the tab is clicked. The below function is called in the parent component of the tab and that is where I want the function call to happen:

```js
 updateactiveTab(activeTab: string) {
    console.log('activetab', activeTab)
    this.activetab = activeTab;
    if(this.activetab === 'Status') {
      console.log('I am in Status tab');
     //Call the method here
    }

  }
```

I get this error:

> Property 'getJobstatusdata' does not exist on type 'typeof JobStatusComponent'.

Comment: If `JobStatusComponent` a child of `TraceLogpageComponent` then you can explore `@ViewChild()`

Comment: do the components have parent-child relation? Then you can simply use [@output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call of the component's method from the other one is a smell. Usually, that means with slight changes in design `@Input` and `@Output` would be suitable. For example `getJobstatusdata(host)` method might be changed so that `host` would be an `@Input` and the `getJobstatusdata` would be call whenever property `@Input() host` is changed.

Anyway, if `JobStatusComponent` is child of the `TraceLogpageComponent` you might leverage `@ViewChild` directive.
Otherwise, I would really suggest reviewing the design. Using a shared service with the observable or move `getJobstatusdata` into service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular service to implement getJobstatusdata() method. Then pass the instance of the new service in constructor of TraceLogpageComponent or JobStatusComponent as you like. You should be able to fetch setTableData without actually calling the api again and again or pass boolean parameter to getJobstatusdata() when you need to refresh table data.